# fullcalendar-rails: different calendars for different events places

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, fullcalendar

I would like to use the gem 'fullcalendar-rails', based on the jQuery FullCalendar plugin from Adam Shaw, to organize my application's events.

I read the useful and well written [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20160531044930/http://blog.crowdint.com/2014/02/18/fancy-calendars-for-your-web-application-with-fullcalendar.html) by Fernando Perales, which is linked in the readme.md file.
Since I would like to use `fullcalendar-rails` for my `Rails 5` application, and I am new with `json`, I would like to ask some questions.

My `Event` model has a `place` attribute, which is the place where the event is held.
My goal is to have different calendars for different places, because each place has its own events.

My idea is to insert in the Events index page the following form:

```
<%= form_tag(events_path, method: :get, id: "search-event-place") do %>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search a place" %>
<%= submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>

<% if @events.present? %>
  <div id="calendar"></div>
<% end %>
```

In this way users can look for a place and get all events held in that place, organised in fullcalendar. So, for instance, if a user search for an event in London, he will get a calendar with events in London...

The index action in the events controller would be as follows:

```
def index
  if params[:search]
    @events = Event.search(params[:search])
  else
    @events = nil
  end
end
```

Would it work if, after defining a `search` method in the `Event` model, I defined the instance variable `@events` used by the `index.json.builder` file as `@events = Event.search(params[:search])` ? 
The search method would be defined in the Event model as follows:

```
def self.search(search)
  where("place ILIKE ?", "#{search}")
end
```

Is the index page of the RESTful Events resource the right place to define `@events`?
What events will I see if I go to: `localhost:3000/events.json` or to: `localhost:3000/events`?

One of my main concerns is this: since the `show` action of the RESTful Events resource corresponds to the url `/events/1` for the event with `id=1`, I wonder if I will be routed correctly using for each event in the `index.json.builder` file the html format which generates a url such as `/events/1.html`. In fact, as common rails practice, I would insert the partial for the generic event in `app/views/events/show.html.erb`

Lastly: my users choose the day of the event with jQuery date picker, so the attribute `event_date` will be saved as a string with format `"yy-mm-dd"`: how can I set json `start` and `end`? Are the `start` and `end` attributes necessary or can I choose only the day of the event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Hello!

### 1. Query

I think this would be more suitable as a `scope`:

```
  scope(:place, ->(search) { where('place LIKE ?', "%#{search}%") })
```

Then you can chain it with other queries and such.

#### Update:

This code should be added to your `Event`-model.
Then you can call `Event.place('search-string').where(sun: true)` or the other way around, it is chainable.

### 2. Controller

You could use the `index` action, i.e.

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json do
      @events = set_events
    end
  end
end

def set_events
  if params[:place].present?
    Event.place(params[:place])
  else
    Event.all
  end
end
```

And if you have an `events#index` route, you can access it with extension `.json` and see the rendered json from your `index.json.jbuilder`.

E.g. if you access `/events` you will see the `index.html.erb` and `/events.json?place=place1` will render all events with a place like `place1` as json.

#### Update

The `format.html` allows rendering html as well as json.

### 3. View

This requires some decisions:

1. Are your places predefined or user input?
2. How do users search for places?

If the places are predefined (or can be accessed) I would render the calendars as:

```
<div class="fullcalendar" data-place="<%= 'place1' %>">
</div>
```

JS:

```
const calendars = document.getElementsByClass('fullcalendar');
Array.from(calendars).forEach(function(calendar) {
  const place = calendar.dataset.place;
  calendar.fullCalendar({
    eventSources: [{ url: '/events.json?place=' + place }],
    other_options:...
  });
});
```

### 4. Rest

I do not understand your concerns regarding `show` or what you mean by the datepicker - please elaborate!

---

## Update

I tried to put everything together in a Gist this time.
https://gist.github.com/davidwessman/7597e3eea4e71238d7f71a74928e64bd please check if out if it helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I edited my original message. My initial intention was to give users the chance of searching for events in their city with a form in the events index page. So this page initially would not show events. When the user search for a place, `@events ` would be defined and fullcalendar rendered in view.

I have a question: where would you put the `scope` in your Query section (section 1)? I am not much familiar with scope.

Also, in the controller, what would correspond to `format.html`?

Comment: Using the `respond_to` and `format` means that you can do different code in the controller if the users tries to access the `html` format or the `json` format.

Comment: Documentation suggests for `fullcalendar-rails` the json format. What would you suggest as html alternative? Also: where would you put the `scope` code?

Comment: The html-format is just for rendering a normal page, not related to fullcalendar.  I added that under scope in the answer - add it to the model.

Comment: Thanks, I will read through your Gist and I will need time for that.